# Как передать данные в AlertDialog?

Tags: android, java

Нужно передать данные в диалог, я сделал отдельный layout, на котором ListView и в который по идее должен писаться весь массив данных, но он не пишется, код ниже:

```
ArrayList<String> matches = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(this);
View content = factory.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);
ListView lv = (ListView) content.findViewById(R.id.list);
lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle("Hello, title!");
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();
lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, matches));
```

Выдает только окошко, в котором написано хелло титле, че не так? Подскажите, плиз.

---

Вопрос решен!

```
ArrayList<String> matches = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
listDialog = new Dialog(this);
listDialog.setTitle("Select Item");
LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View v = li.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null, false);
listDialog.setContentView(v);
listDialog.setCancelable(true);
// there are a lot of settings, for dialog, check them all out!
ListView list1 = (ListView) listDialog.findViewById(R.id.list);
// list1.setOnItemClickListener(this);
list1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, matches));
listDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А что ты хочешь что бы оно выдавало?

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle("Hello, title!");
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();
```

вот оно, не какого кастомногоо списка в него не кладется.
Дальше в таком коде, лучше пользоваться методами - читабельней будет.
И я бы такую задачу делал не через диалог, а через Активити с диалог-стилем.